# What are the zero values (default values without explicit initialization) for different Go types?

Tags: go

Go gives default values, or *zero values*, for variables that are declared without an explicit initialization. What are the different zero values for builtin types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Booleans: *false*
- Integers: 0
- Floats: 0.0
- Strings: ""
- Pointers: nil
- Functions: nil
- Interfaces: nil
- Slices: nil
- Channels: nil
- Maps: nil

This is done recursively, so arrays and structs (and arrays of structs etc.) will have their uninitialized values set to the zero values described above.

This also applies when using *new* and *make* to allocate storage for variables.

Source: http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value